# Flex item not going to next row (not wrapping)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why isn't the flex item going to the next row?

The flex item just pushes to side.

```css
.section-header {
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  //padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: blue;
}

.section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: orange;
  padding: 20px;
}

.desc-label {
  padding-top: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.row {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  //flex-direction: column;
  //align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 400px;
}

.section-title {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="row section-header">
    <div class="section-title">Engine</div>
    <div class="desc-label">Template Element: Recipe Ingredient</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rQVbMr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-wrap: nowrap`. This means that flex items, by default, are forced to remain on a single line.

You can override the default by adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to the container ([revised demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXVvKp)).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap